how to calculate average daily balance - current cycle
I have this data and i want to calculate,
average daily balance - current cycle: $1,595.49.
I try mean median mode and manulay sum / T rows but all results different
fd  tr_type amount  date            balance
8   credit  789.81  2/2/2024    789.81
8   credit  529.98  2/15/2024   1319.79
8   debit   29      2/15/2024   1290.79
8   debit   95.99   2/20/2024   1194.8
8   credit  1000    2/21/2024   2194.8
8   credit  494.12  2/22/2024   2688.92
8   debit   10      2/22/2024   2678.92
8   debit   1405    2/22/2024   1273.92
8   debit   15      2/23/2024   1258.92
8   credit  571     2/27/2024   1829.92
8   credit  533.8   2/29/2024   1258.92
8   credit  0.05    2/29/2024   1829.92
8   debit   123.07  3/6/2024    2240.7
8   debit   186.58  3/6/2024    2054.12
8   credit  516.4   3/7/2024    2570.52
8   debit   138.53  3/7/2024    2431.99
8   debit   510.23  3/8/2024    1921.76

then i try daily balance * by number of days in between dates then t sum and divide number of month days it gives near about result 99.9 % correct (little difference in 0.02)
Kindly check this sheet link . I added 3 sheet there, my table structure, amount calculation which i can change not necessary, and what i want as avg balance which is manulay calculated in last sheet and i want MYSQL QUERY for those calculation. I want query which just give me average balance amount 1,595.49
I try this query but its not working,it calculate on first row with date differnce only. But i want to calculate for all rows .
SELECT date1, fd, balance, CASE WHEN next_date IS NOT NULL THEN DATEDIFF(next_date, date1) * amount ELSE 1* amount END AS adjusted_amount FROM ( SELECT date1, transaction_type, amount, fd, (SELECT SUM( CASE WHEN t.transaction_type = 'credit' THEN t.amount WHEN t.transaction_type = 'debit' THEN -t.amount ELSE 0 END ) FROM transactions t WHERE fd='8' AND t.date1 <= transactions.date1) AS balance , LEAD(date1) OVER (PARTITION BY fd ORDER BY date1 ASC) AS next_date FROM transactions WHERE fd='8' ) subquery ORDER BY date1 ASC;

these calculaions already done in this bank statement.

See Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question, #5 and #3

Please edit your question and explain fully and in a detailed manner what exactly you intend to achieve. Your question, as it stands explains what you tried, which is good. But it is unclear what you intended to do and exactly how your current try failed. In order to answer your question I would take a look at your intention and write a query from scratch. But I need to understand what your goal is in order to be able to do so.

https://i.sstatic.net/3GUosYlD.png
as you can see in this image.
daily balance * by number of days in betwen dates then total sum and divide number of month days it gives near about result 99.9 % correct.
this work for me in excel. but i want mysql query for exactly that solution.

Without being able to establish the last balance figure for a day (eod) this is not possible. Do you have something in addition to date which would help?

my current table structure is
id
fd
check-no
transaction_type
amount
transaction_date
description
date1
i can add more clumn if you guide me !

@waqasss, Given the 2 lines 10/20/2024 1194.8 1194 and 10/21/2024 2194.8 2194.8, why is the day differnce * balance 1194 instead of 1194.8 for a one day balance of 1194.8?  Looks like a formula problem in cell C5.  What is the formula?

Not quite sure what the average daily balance is exactly in this case. Does it include dates with no transactions or not, do you want a running average daily balance, or, maybe, monthly ???
One thing could help you resolve it, though...

... but i want last row of balance on same date ...

WITH    --  Getting last balance of the day ordered per date by tr_type 
    day_balances AS
      ( Select    a.a_date, a.balance as day_balance
        From    ( Select    Row_Number() Over(Order By fd, a_date, tr_type) as rn, 
                            t.*, 
                            Row_Number() Over(Partition By fd, a_date Order By fd, a_date, tr_type) as a_date_rn,
                            Count(*) Over(Partition By fd, a_date) as a_date_count
                  From      tbl t
                ) a
        Where    a.a_date_rn = a.a_date_count
        Order By a.a_date
      )
Select * From day_balances Order By a_date;

/*    R e s u l t :  
a_date      day_balance
----------  -----------
2024-02-02       789.81
2024-02-15      1290.79
2024-02-20      1194.80
2024-02-21      2194.80
2024-02-22      1273.92
2024-02-23      1258.92
2024-02-27      1829.92
2024-02-29      1829.92
2024-03-06      2054.12
2024-03-07      2431.99
2024-03-08      1921.76      */

Regarding:

then i try daily balance * by number of days in between dates then t sum and divide number of month days it gives near about result 99.9 % correct (little difference in 0.03)

Using your data from picture below quoted text and the logic that you used - the code and result should be like here:
WITH
    day_balances AS
  ( Select    a.a_date, a.balance as day_balance
    From    ( Select    Row_Number() Over(Order By fd, a_date, tr_type) as rn, 
                        t.*, 
                        Row_Number() Over(Partition By fd, a_date Order By fd, a_date, tr_type) as a_date_rn,
                        Count(*) Over(Partition By fd, a_date) as a_date_count
              From      tbl t
            ) a
    Where    a.a_date_rn = a.a_date_count
    Order By a.a_date
  )

--      S Q L : 
SELECT   a_date, day_balance, next_date, day_diff, cum_balance, 
         Sum(day_diff) 
             Over(Order By a_date 
                  Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And Current Row) as cum_days,
         --
         Round( Sum(cum_balance)  
                    Over(Order By a_date 
                         Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And Current Row) / 
                Sum(day_diff) 
                     Over(Order By a_date 
                          Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And Current Row), 6 ) as cum_AVG_so_far
FROM (
Select   a_date, day_balance, 
         Coalesce(LEAD(a_date) Over(Order By a_date), a_date) as next_date, 
        DATEDIFF( Coalesce(LEAD(a_date) Over(Order By a_date), a_date + INTERVAL '1' Day), a_date ) as day_diff,
        DATEDIFF( Coalesce(LEAD(a_date) Over(Order By a_date), a_date + INTERVAL '1' Day ), a_date ) * day_balance as cum_balance
From     day_balances
    ) x
ORDER BY a_date

/*      R e s u l t : 
a_date      day_balance  next_date   day_diff    cum_balance  cum_days  day_AVG_so_far  cum_AVG_so_far
----------  -----------  ----------  --------  -------------  --------  --------------  --------------
2024-10-10       789.81  2024-10-15         5        3949.05         5      789.810000      789.810000
2024-10-15      1289.80  2024-10-20         5        6449.00        10     1039.805000     1039.805000
2024-10-20      1194.80  2024-10-21         1        1194.80        11     1091.470000     1053.895455
2024-10-21      2194.80  2024-10-22         1        2194.80        12     1367.302500     1148.970833
2024-10-22      1273.92  2024-10-23         1        1273.92        13     1348.626000     1158.582308
2024-10-23      1258.92  2024-10-27         4        5035.68        17     1333.675000     1182.191176
2024-10-27      1829.92  2024-10-29         2        3659.84        19     1404.567143     1250.373158
2024-10-29      2363.77  2024-11-06         8       18910.16        27     1524.467500     1580.268519
2024-11-06      2240.70  2024-11-07         1        2240.70        28     1604.048889     1603.855357
2024-11-07      2431.99  2024-11-08         1        2431.99        29     1686.843000     1632.411724
2024-11-08      1921.76  2024-11-08         1        1921.76        30     1708.199091     1642.056667      */

The result is 1642.056667 which is different from your calculation.
Differences:

your calc for 2024-10-29 is based on 6 days untill the next date - that should be 8 days couse the next date 2024-11-06
I ordered the day transactions by  tr_type (credit first - debit last), so, for 2024-11-06, I got the balance of 2240.7 - your balance for same date taken into calculation is 2054.12
Last date's balance (2024-11-08) is doubled in your calculation for some reason
And finaly - your calculation uses total number of days (from start to end of table data) as 29 - it should be 30 couse both the starting date and the ending date should be included.

I did correction of my code to act like your calculation and that code results with 1595.494483 as you would expect.
You can see both calculations in the fiddle here.

kindly check this sheet link . i added 3 sheet there, my table structure, amount calculation which i can change not necessary, and what i want as avg balance which is manulay calculated in last sheet and i want MYSQL QUERY for those calculation. i want query which just give me average balance amount 1,595.49
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vuUJbP3rp31SmLE5u83JqY0Xk3KSmtDwhI917E2nwvU/edit?usp=sharing

@waqasss As said and showed before - this can be forced to act as your calculation but it could be hard to explain the differences listed in the answer. The code that results as asked for is here --> https://dbfiddle.uk/TCvUuata .
